# Serialize a "Driver"

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class that is a "Generic Network Device". I would like to support the concept of a Driver. I have written a "Driver" Interface with a certain set of methods.

Given that a user has entered information for a "Generic Network Device", I would like them to be able to download Serialized "Drivers" that I write that will then cast the "Generic Network Device" into a certain "Specific Network Device".

What I'm struggling to understand is How to Open a saved "Driver" and be able to apply it to the "Generic Network Device". For example, if I extend "Driver", when my Application Deserializes my new Extended Driver, how will it know what to cast it to?

```
public abstract class Driver<N extends DefaultDevice, D extends DefaultDevice, R> implements ReturnInterface<R>,Serializable {

N userSuppliedDevice;
protected static String NAME="Driver";
public Driver(N n) {
    this.userSuppliedDevice = n;
}

public Driver() {

}

public void setDefaultDevice(N n) {
    this.userSuppliedDevice = n;
}

/**
 * Gets the Generic Device before the driver is applied.
 *
 * @return
 */
public N getDefaultDevice() {
    return this.userSuppliedDevice;
}

public abstract Double getVersion();

public abstract String getName();

/**
 * Gets the Specific Device after the driver is applied.
 *
 * @return
 */
public abstract D getReturnedDevice();

public abstract String getSnapShotCommands();


public static void SAVE(Object o, String fileName) throws IOException{
    String path=System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Documents"+File.separator+fileName;
    System.out.println("Path= "+path);
    Serializer.serialize(new File(path), o);

}

 }
```

Comment: "How will it know what to cast it to?" It won't.

Comment: Right, so how do people resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that you have `NetworkDevice` and `Driver` in your classpath during compiletime, and you want to have `FooDriver` and `FooNetworkDevice` at runtime? With `FooDriver` being loaded from somewhere and "converting" the regular `NetworkDevice` to a `FooNetworkDevice`?

Comment: Unless there is a better solution out there, I think I will just re-write Driver to be an Interface, that way it won't matter what specific class you cast to.

Comment: It's not about a better solution. That's the only solution. You can load classes at runtime, but you need to cast them to a known subclass or interface in order to use them.

Comment: @Kayaman No, I'm saying at some point in time I will write updated drivers or drivers for different kinds of devices, and I want them to be imported into my app to be able to be applied to devices the user has already created. I won't be able to control when and what is available at compiletime except for the base classes.

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: @Kayaman, How do people typically make a new instance of a serialized class? Include a static Method for doing so? I need to have the Driver and assign a new instance of the driver to each device its assigned to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125537/discussion-between-jamie-snipes-and-kayaman).

Comment: Serialization is for *instances*. Then you have dynamic classloading, which is different.

Comment: Do you believe this example would be best resolved with dynamic classloading?

Comment: Well if you intend to use classes that you don't have present when you're compiling your application, then you don't really have a choice. But you've got a bit of reading to do before you continue writing code.